# How to use standard aluminium extrusions

Tags: beam, solidworks

How to use standard aluminum extrusions and accessories at Solidworks? I believe there are some libraries, but I don't know how to click or download them. Would you please teach me how to do it? Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Youtube has a lot of stuff. Until you get an answer, go to youtube.com and search for adding aluminum extrusion libraries to solidworks. Try different keywords too like 8020, 80/20, etc.

Comment: 8020.net and McMaster-Carr have CAD libraries for most modeling packages, if you can use CAD you should be able to figure out how to download the parts...

Comment: That's right jko! These sites had downloads for almost any CAD system of virtually all their stuff.